# JMeter remote server - hundreds of one to one tests

Tags: csv, jmeter

I need to test a set of HTTP Tomcat servers using JMeter. I have a list of 'n' target servers and a list of 'n' JMeter remote test servers and a list of a single variable parameters that will be tested in the URL against each Tomcat server. However, each JMeter remote test server should test only a single target server with a set of threads cycling through all the parameters - so the test is 1 to 1 but I need to collate the results as the target servers form a CDN edge set with a common origin URL.
How could I ensure that each target server is tested by a single JMeter server using the same set of parameters? Using a CSV DATA SET CONFIG for the list of parameters is obvious but I can't see how I could use the same type of config element for the list of target servers.

The only way I can envision it is that I distribute a csv file containing a single unique target URL to each remote JMeter server. That way all the hundreds of threads on each JMeter server only know about one target but can use a single filename for the source URL. Does anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter remove "slaves" basically execute the same test plan which is being specified on the "master" machine so default configuration is not something you can use.

There are 2 options:

1. You can modify *user.properties* file on each slave machine to contain the single unique endpoint (URL) like:

   - in *user.properties* file define a property which will specify the endpoint:

     ```
     url=http://some.cdn.1
     ```
   - in the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the value like:

     ```
     ${__P(url)}
     ```

   So given different `url` property on each remote slave each slave will be hitting different endpoint. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information regarding JMeter properties and ways of working with them.
2. You can use [__machipeIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) or [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) function in conjunction with the [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) so switch execution branches basing on the "slave" IP address or hostname, something like:

   - If Controller, condition: `${__machineIP()} == "172.30.40.50"`

     - do something specific for CDN1
   - If Controller, condition: `${__machineIP()} == "172.30.40.51"`

     - do something specific for CDN2
   - etc.